# does call forwarding work with the cellular provider

Tags: calls

Android has a feature to set up call forwarding. Does this send a command to my cellular provider or is it something the phone does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's something done at your ISP's server side.

To make a test: Configure it, and shutdown your phone. Grab another phone and call, you'll see you don't get a "User has shut down" prompt but directly connect to someone (you've set).